# Mortar: having a few instances of the same view in one Activity

Tags: android, mortar

Is it possible to have few instances of the same view inside of one Activity with Mortar library?
How to initialize Activity's scope in this case?
Or should somehow create a separate scope for each view?

What I want:

MyActivity
     - MyView (id:1)
     - MyView (id:2)

I've tried, but my Presenter's onLoad/onSave are all become messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to set up subscopes for the children. Or ever, really, that's always an optimization.

Presenters always have to be a singleton, so if you need to have several views showing the same type of Presenter at once, you'll need to do something to make a singleton per view. E.g. you could have a base class for the Presenter and have subclasses for the individual view types, or could use a binding annotation (e.g. @Inject @TheBlueOne MyPresenter presenter;).

If you're doing something more dynamic, like making a list of subviews that all need the same type of presenter, you might make the parent view's presenter a factory of sub-presenters. One thought:

```
ParentView {
  void addRow(int id) {
    MyRowView newRow = new MyRowView(getContext(), presenter);
    newRow.setId(id);
    addChild(newRow);
  }
}

ChildView {
  final ParentPresenter parentPresenter;
  ChildPresenter presenter;

  public ChildView(Context context, ParentPresenter parentPresenter) {
    super(context);
    this.parentPresenter = parentPresenter;
  }

  protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    presenter = parentPresenter.getChild(getId());
    presenter.takeView(this);
  }

  protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    presenter.dropView(this);
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
  }
}

@Singleton
ParentPresenter {
  final Map<Integer, ChildPresenter> childrens = new HashMap<>();
  final Provider<ChildPresenter> childrensProvider;

  @Inject
  ParentPresenter(Provider<ChildPresenter> childrensProvider) {
    this.childrensProvider = childrensProvider;
  }

  ChildPresenter getChild(int id) {
    ChildPresenter child = childrens.get(id);
    if (childPresenter == null) {
      child = childrensProvider.get();
      childrens.put(id, child);
    }
    return child;
  }
}
```